# Windows 10 folder organizer

Tags: windows-10

Please suggest me a program with which I can put folders on categories, like this:
https://prnt.sc/nb3aw6

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question feels a little too broad / vague, but if I understood correctly, what you want is called a "tag based file manager".

I don't have a first hand experience, a quick search showed me a few. Some that stood out for me were [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/), [TagFlow](http://www.tagflow.ch/en/) and [Elyse](https://silkwoodsoftware.com/).

TagSpaces is free and open source, but have a "Pro" version which costs 39 EUR;
TagFlow is currently free, but with plans to add some paid features in the future;
Elyse is paid, 10 USD.

Since the print attached only showed pictures, if you're looking for an organizer just for your pictures, then you should look for "media gallery organizers", such as [Adobe Bridge](https://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html).

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you!